# Pdf does not appears on Android

Tags: android, pdf, react-native

I'm using the library react-native-pdf to show it.
Its frame is okay because I've set the background in blue.
I'm doing a RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(path) just before and the value is true but nothing appears on pdf viewer

Any idea ? I have no log or whatever which tell me there is a problem.

```
<Pdf source={{uri : filePath}}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', flex : 1}}/>
```

Here is how I show the pdf.

```
const request = RNFetchBlob
  .config(this.getConfig(title, ext))
  .fetch('GET', uri, header);

this.setState(
  () => {
    return {request: request}
  },
  () => {
    this.state.request.then((res) => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

          const path = res.path()
          const infos = res.info()
          console.log(infos)


          if (path !== undefined){

            this.setState(() => {
              return {
                filePath : path
              }
            })
```

The file path is returned by the res.path()

```
addAndroidDownloads: {
      useDownloadManager: true,
      notification: false,
      path: filePath,
      description: `${title}`,
      mediaScannable: true,
    }
```

The variable config is made like this.

Comment: Could you please add some code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: I added some code. As you can see, everything should be allright